# In what proportion should water be mixed with spirit to gain 12.5% by selling it at cost price?

Tags: arithmetic, percentages, ratio

How to solve this problem by using laws of proportions analytically?

> In what proportion should water be mixed with spirit to gain 12.5% by selling it at cost price?

Doubt:

I feel that the problem is best solved by using some trivial analytical skills to approach it. What is particularly confusing about the problem is that how do I use the analytical skills to get to the problem directly?

Comment: Suppose that you add enough water so that the $100\%$ spirit is reduced to only $(8/9)$ as strong as it was.  This implies that you are selling $(8/9)$ the amount of spirits for the full price.  Now suppose that you are selling $(9/8)$ of the mixture.  This means that you are selling $(8/9) \times (9/8) = 1$ amount of spirits (the old amount).  However, your price has increased from $(1)$ to $(9/8)$, which means that you have added a profit of $(1/8)$, which translates to $12.5\%$.  So, how must water do you add to spirits to reduce the percentage of spirits from $100\%$ to $(8/9)$?

Comment: You used two quantities namely 8/9 and 9/8 here. What is exactly meant in the context? What are both the quantities really?

Comment: I don't understand your question.  $(8/9)$ and $(9/8)$ are fractions.

Comment: @user2661923 Can you write a more structural answer to the main question?

Comment: No, I am not allowed to, because your question has a number of defects that need to be repaired, before the mathSE protocol permits a reviewer to provide an answer.  See [this article](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33190/how-to-avoid-downvotes-for-beginners-questions/33236#33236) for details.